# The output of my ArrayList is different on another web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I am trying to show a list of pre generated voucher codes (when a button is clicked). I have set up a working process and everything looks like it should work as designed. However, after creating and storing the generated codes, I try to retrieve the code to find that it is now different.

I have an ArrayList on my Login page that holds the codes generated during the session.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["GenList"] = new ArrayList();
    }
```

Here is the method used to generate the code and store it (in my voucher generating Class):

```
protected void GenCode()
    {
        string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        char[] stringChars = new char[5];
        Random random = new Random();

        ArrayList GeneratedCodes = (ArrayList)Session["GenList"];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = letters[random.Next(letters.Length)];
        }

        string finalCode = new string(stringChars);

        if (GeneratedCodes.Contains(finalCode))
        {
            VCodeAnnouncement.Visible = false;
            DiscountLabel.Visible = false;
            VCode.Text = "There are no valid codes left";
        }
        else
        {
            GeneratedCodes.Add(finalCode);
            Session["GenList"] = GeneratedCodes;
            VCode.Text = finalCode;         
        }
    }
```

And finally here is my Button_Click event handler in another class:

```
protected void VoucherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList GenCodes = (ArrayList)Session["GenList"];
    for (int i = 1; i < GenCodes.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GenCodes[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

An example of the problem would be a code generated such as: CJIKK, and then being shown as: OVTIC.

Does it have something to do with the fact that I am changing the stored object back into a string? If so what could I do to remedy this?

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session is different for every user. If you see the page with two different users, the list will be different.

The Session times-out, so if the user session times out, when he enters the site again, the list will be different.

An finally, when you show the voucher codes you're starting at index 1 instead of 0.

One of this must be the reason.

Comment: It was the last solution, must have mistyped haha. I have noticed now however that 2 codes are stored for every 1 generated.